# Pipe to GNU Plot problems in C

Tags: c, arrays, gnuplot, histogram, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>
void plotResults(double* xData, double* yData, int dataSize);  
int main()
{  
int i = 0;
int d1, d2, d3;
int a[16];
    srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i <= 15; i++)   
    a[i] = 0;   
for(i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)   
{   
    d1 = rand() % 6 + 1;   //randomized dice rolls
    d2 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    d3 = rand() % 6 + 1;  
    ++a[d1 + d2 + d3 - 3];   
}  
char asterisks[0x400];
memset(asterisks, '*', sizeof(asterisks)); //copies the character value to the # of                                                                       bytes to be set to the value


int nIntervals = 0;      
double* xData = (double*) malloc((nIntervals+1)*sizeof(double));  
double* yData = (double*) malloc((nIntervals+1)*sizeof(double));  
xData[0] = 0.0;  
double x0 = 0.0;  
for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) {  
        x0 = xData[i];  
        xData[i+1] = x0 + 1;  
}  
for (i = 0; i <= nIntervals; i++) {  
        x0 = xData[i];  
        yData[i] = a[i];  
    }  
plotResults(xData,yData,nIntervals);  
return 0;  
}  
void plotResults(double* xData, double* yData, int dataSize) {  
  FILE *gnuplotPipe,*tempDataFile;  
  char *tempDataFileName;  
  double x,y;  
  int i;  
  tempDataFileName = "tempData";  
  gnuplotPipe = popen("/usr/bin/X11/gnuplot -persist","w");  
  if (gnuplotPipe) {  
      fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"plot \"%s\" with lines\n",tempDataFileName);  
      fflush(gnuplotPipe);  
      tempDataFile = fopen(tempDataFileName,"w");  
      for (i=0; i <= dataSize; i++) {  
          x = xData[i];  
          y = yData[i];              
          fprintf(tempDataFile,"%lf %lf\n",x,y);          
  }          
  fclose(tempDataFile);          
  printf("press enter to continue...");          
  getchar();          
  remove(tempDataFileName);          
  fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"exit \n");      
  } else {          
      printf("gnuplot not found...");      
  }
```

I need to get this program working, taking a dice rolling algorithm, and printing out a histogram of graph.

Directions: This program should re-use the code produced in a previous lab to simulate the outcome of rolling three dice and taking the total of the individual outcomes. The histogram should be produced by the gnuplot package driven by your C program. You should write a function to deal with the pipe, taking as input a pointer to an array of histogram data (HISTOGRAM), and the array size. It should then perform the following steps:
   Open a pipe to gnuplot
    if pipe exists, send commands
     flush the pipe
      open a temporary file to store histogram data
      write histogram data on temporary file
     close temporary file
      pause program using getchar()
      remove temporary file
  return with no error code
The main function should initialize an array of HISTOGRAM data and perform the simulation of the dice throws using C's functions srand and rand.

Comment: What is not working? Please explain in detail the part that is not working and explain what it is doing that is wrong. What other things have you tried?

Comment: it is not storing the x and y values into the tempdata file. I changed alittle bit and it runs but the file it is trying to plot doesn't get the updated y and x values

Comment: I think the problem is that you are writing the temp file after you plot it.  Write `tempData` first, then close it, then send it to `gnuplot`.

Comment: Its quite unnecessary, that you repost the very same question with a new account: [Histogram dice roll produced by gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19634776/2604213)